# Why there is no CriteriaQuery<T>#where(List<Predicate>)?

Tags: java, jpa, criteria-api

I'm curious about the absence of `CriteriaQuery<T>#where(List<Predicate>)`.

I see `orderBy(List<Order>)`, `multiselect(List<Selection<?>>)` and `groupBy(List<Expression<?>>)`.

Why there is no method for `where(List<Predicate>)`? Is there any technical reason for that?

Comment: Why ask that here? The better, more logical place, would be the JPA spec mailing list, since they allegedly had some reason for the assorted missing methods https://accounts.eclipse.org/mailing-list/jpa-dev

Comment: The rationale *might have been* that even the `where(Predicate...)` method would rarely be used with more than one `Predicate`, since `Predicate`s are typically joined together using `CriteriaBuilder.and()`/`CriteriaBuilder.or()` (similarly, you use `AND/OR` to join conditions in `JPQL` as opposed to using comma-separated lists with `SELECT`, `GROUP BY`, and `ORDER BY`)

Answer (score 1):

The where(..) method does not have the signature: `where(List<Predicate>)`. From the implementation perspective, usually a list is used to store predicates internally. For the method `where(Predicate ...)`, the array will be converted to list. So the `where(List<Predicate>)` is more efficient than `where(Predicate ...)`. A request should be submitted to JPA specification.

Answer (score 0):

You must build criteria predicates first using eg `CriteriaBuilder` to create `CriteriaQuery`. All predicates are there by the time you will get `CriteriaQuery.

Besides, there is `where` in CriteriaQuery

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaQuery.html#where(javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate...)

Comment: I'm asking for the absence of `where(List<Predicate>)`. I'm already aware of the `where(Predicate...)`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I got your question correctly or not, but I used sth like the code below and use `where` with a list of predicate!

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery =criteriaBuilder.createQuery();
List<Predicate> predicates = new 
ArrayList<Predicate>();
Predicate predicate = null;
predicate = criteriaBuilder.equal(path, value);
predicates.add(predicate);
criteriaQuery.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[]{}));
```